# Laravel Gitlab CI/CD, ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Tags: php, laravel, gitlab

I've added a default Laravel CI, but I always get errors. Can anybody help?

See Full CI Output on Gitlab: https://gitlab.com/domezi/s2/-/jobs/657363936

tail:

```
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for zip archive read/write support... yes, shared
checking for libzip >= 0.11 libzip != 1.3.1 libzip != 1.7.0... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libzip >= 0.11 libzip != 1.3.1 libzip != 1.7.0) were not met:
No package 'libzip' found
No package 'libzip' found
No package 'libzip' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBZIP_CFLAGS
and LIBZIP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: `No package 'libzip' found` - what have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: [Here is an information how to install _libzip_](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libzip-dev), which could help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing libzip package, so you need to include [libzip-dev](https://libzip.org/) package as well.

In your .gitlab-ci.yml file istead of:

```
  # Install dependencies
  - apt-get install libonig-dev git nodejs libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev -yqq
```

You need to have:

```
  # Install dependencies
  - apt-get install libonig-dev git nodejs libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev libzip-dev -yqq
```

Then this error should not happen anymore.